# Help needed to design a suitable energy harvester for TENG

Tags: low-power, impedance-matching, energy-harvesting

I am in the process of desgining a scalable triboelectric nanogenerator (TENG) through which I can easily harvest and store electricity in a battery or a capacitor.

A TENG can be modelled as voltage source and a capacitor as illustrated as below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6g45M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem with this model is that it has a very high impedance and for maximum power transfer we need impedance matching. One idea that I had is using coupling inductors (transformer action) to bring down the voltage and upscale the current so that the impedance on the load side is reflected as Z/n^2.

I am not sure that this technique will work.

After rectifying this low frequency AC generated I have found some energy harvesters by Linear Technology but they are pretty expensive and keeping the costs low is the main goal as for now.

Here are the links of the two that I found:

[LTC3588 evaluation board.](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/DC1459B-A/DC1459B-A-ND/4866554?cur=EUR&lang=en)

[ADP5091 evaluation board.](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-adp5091.html#eb-overview)

What factors beside the costs should I need to keep in mind in order to decide which of these devices would better suit my need?

Also what would be the modular breakdown of such a nano energy harvester so that I can design it for myself?

Comment: A series inductor can cancel the capacitive impedance in the TENG and provide a low impedance path to the energy source but it then becomes a tuned circuit and this will become less effective if the frequency changes or the capacitor value changes.

Comment: Just an FYI, looking at the Linear part, it includes a rectifier bridge, unlike the Analog Devices part, some savings there perhaps.

Comment: @Andyaka I was thinking of using a step down transformer to reduce the impedance by a factor of n^2. But I sincerely doubt that I will be able to get any output from the transformer since the power is extremely small and frequency is below 10Hz.